# PowerBI Dax - Display row based on certain condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I got two filter **(Company Name & Vessel Name)** and **one table** as below; I got three condition to fulfil

[image]

First one, if company name and vessel name filter is selected at same time, table will show detail with status FAIL, As example, Jimmy and Ali Anca shown with fail status

[image]

Second condition is, if **only** vessel filter is selected, table will show detail with only TRUE status. As example, when Ali Anca is selected, table show Ali Anca with TRUE status;

[image]

Third condition is, when **both** filter is not selected, All data will be shown on table with only TRUE status as below;

[image]

Really appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: Sorry, the first condition with status FALSE, not FAIL

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer. We can use isFiltered function. My DAX as below;

```
Switch( true() ,
calculate(countrows(Table) , filter(Table, Table[Status] = FALSE())),
isfiltered(Table[Companyname]) && isfiltered(Table[VessalName]) ,
calculate(countrows(Table) , filter(Table, Table[Status] = TRUE()))
)
```

Thanks!